# How to use typeid to store a type_info object

Tags: c++

I am trying to create and store a type_info object:

```
#include <typeinfo>
int i;
type_info x = typeid(i);
```

And an error message is generated. Is there any way to store a type_info object?

The history behind this is that I am trying to generate test cases for various C++ integer types; doing arithmetic on them and determining whether intermediate results are promoted to the next largest integer type or truncated. That is:

```
unsigned char x = 257;
unsigned char y = 257;
// is (x + y) == 514 or 256?
```

And decided to do a type check against a static data structure, for example:

```
int x = <value>;
int y = <value>;
static type_info def = { typeid(bool)
                       , typeid(char),  typeid(unsigned char)
                       , typeid(short), typeid(unsigned short)
                       , typeid(long),  typeid(unsigned long)
                       };
type_info obj = typeid(x + y);
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(def)/sizeof(def[0]); i++) if (obj == def[i]); break;
```

Anyhow, it can't be done without being able to store the type_info structure and I would still like to find out about integer promotions.

Can you create a type_info object? The gcc 4.5.3 implementation has assignment as private.

Is there a resource telling when integer promotions are performed?

thanks

Comment: You might be better off using [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) as it provides the information you are testing for. Just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

`typeid()` returns a `const type_info &` and `type_info` has a private copy constructor, so you can't build the array you describe.  I can't find anything to say whether they are persistent, but you could try `type_info *a[] = { &typeid(int), ... }`

Comment: Thanks. Did the trick. The actual code is: 
[code]
type_info* x = const_cast<type_info*>(&typeid(uChar));
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, (gcc 4.5.1 works)  this kind of thing may work:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types>
struct Seq {};

template<typename T, typename Seq, typename=void>
struct IndexOf;

template<typename T, typename First, typename... Types>
struct IndexOf<T, Seq<First, Types...>, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, First>::value >::type > {
  enum { value = 0 };
};
template<typename T, typename First, typename... Types>
struct IndexOf<T, Seq<First, Types...>, typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<T, First>::value >::type > {
  enum { value = 1+IndexOf<T,Seq<Types...>>::value };
};

typedef Seq< bool, char, unsigned char, short, unsigned short, int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long > IntegerTypes;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int x = 7;
  int y = 10;
  std::cout << IndexOf< decltype(x+y), IntegerTypes >::value << "\n";
  // this next line will not compile, because void is not in the IntegerTypes sequence:
  // std::cout << IndexOf< void, IntegerTypes >::value << "\n";
}
```

but you'll note it doesn't depend on the values of x or y, just their types.

Note that all of the logic is done at compile time, not at run time.  And if you pass a type that isn't in the list, you get a spew of error messages (whose proper interpretation is "not found").  I could have made the error messages shorter, but I'm lazy.  :)

Comment: I did not use this as a solution. The question that I need answering is whether a computation causes integer promotion (such as (x << 1) + 1, where x = 0x80, is the answer '1' or '0x101?). I'm not sure that a static evaluation would yield the correct result. But thanks.

Comment: @user426696 The type of an arithmetic expression in C++ is statically evaluated.  The type of `(x<<1)+1` does not depend on the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`type_info` is not copy-constructible, but there's a wrapper for it, called [`type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), which is. And it also provides `name()` and `hash_code()` methods as well as comparison operators, so for most purposes it's just as good as a copy of `type_info` — or even better, since it's ordered, unlike `type_info`.